# How do I change the popover's text when a button is clicked?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use [ngx-bootstrap's popover.](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/popover?tab=overview) What I want to happen is, a button will have a popover that says "Copy", when the button is clicked, the popover text should change to "Copied!". When the button is hovered again, the text should be "Copy" again. For some reason, my code isn't working. The text is still "Copy", it never changes.

Here's what my code looks like:

html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary small" data-testid="copy-button"
        [popover]="copyText" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"
        (click)="copyToClipboard()"
      >
```

component.ts

```
public copyText = 'Copy';

constructor() {}

public copyToClipboard() {

    if(this.summary?.summary === undefined) {
      return;
    }

    this.copyText = 'Copied!';
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(this.summary.summary);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.copyText = 'Copy';
    }, 1000);
  }
```

I have tried changeDetector.detectChanges() but nothing happens. It does not work.

```
constructor(
    private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) { }

  public copyToClipboard() {
    if(this.summary?.summary === undefined) {
      return;
    }

    this.copyText = 'Copied!';
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(this.summary.summary);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.copyText = 'Copy';
    }, 1000);
  }
```

I have also tried setTimeout, but it does not work.

```
public copyToClipboard() {
    if(this.summary?.summary === undefined) {
      return;
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.copyText = 'Copied!';
    }, 0);

    navigator.clipboard.writeText(this.summary.summary);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.copyText = 'Copy';
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Do note that summary is not empty and not undefined, so it should pass the first statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I was able to get a hint on [github](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/4273). Basically, I have to create a popover template, and use that.

Here's the final code:

```
public copyToClipboard() {
    if(this.summary?.summary === undefined) {
      return;
    }

    this.copyText = 'Copied!';

    navigator.clipboard.writeText(this.summary.summary);

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.copyText = 'Copy';
    }, 1000);
  }
```

```
<ng-template #popTemplate>{{copyText}}</ng-template>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary small" data-testid="copy-button"
        [popover]="popTemplate" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"
        (click)="copyToClipboard()"
      >
```